# Can't find error in my factoring code

Tags: python

I'm trying to factor N! This is my code:

```
total = 0
i = 1
for i in range (N):
  total = total + N
  print (str(total))
  print('Final total : ' + str(total))
```

I keep getting this error

```
Program Failed for Input: 4
Expected Output: 24
Your Program Output: 4
Final total : 4
8
Final total : 8
12
Final total : 12
16
Final total : 16
```

I was given no examples on how to do this and only got this far because of some YouTube videos, I'm willing to put in the work if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=factorial It is product, not sum.

Comment: Learn the difference between factorial and sum.

Comment: You did not implement the factorial on N, you produce the *square* of N instead.

Comment: The code keeps adding N, not i. Even if the question asked for the sum of all values up to N, the result would be wrong. It returns N*N ,not N!

Comment: Also, it looks like whatever software is judging your output is only seeing the first 4. You probably want to move that to outside the loop.

Comment: total = 1
N = 12
i = 1
for i in range (N):
  total = total * N
  N= N-1
print (str(total))
  
print('Final total : ' + str(total))

Answer (score 0):

There are a few erros in you code, look first factorial is multiplication, not sum, then, you have to mult the index, not the constant, it would be:

```
total = 1
i = 1
N = 10
for i in range (i,N):
  total = total * i
  print (str(total))
  print('Final total : ' + str(total))
```

Comment: That's not a factorial either. You probably meant `total = total * i`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I did, you are right, I paste the wrong code haha, that's now is factorial :), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Factorial is the product of an integer and all the  non-negative integer below

```
total = 1
N = 12
i = 1
for i in range (N):
  total = total * N #product of an integer
  N= N-1 #and all the integers below

print (str(total))

print('Final total : ' + str(total))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man this has really helped me out, I was worried about this.